# Behind view accessible though view is disable mac os x

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsview, nsbutton

I am using [LIBRARY](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/itsidebar) in my mac application. and problem is here like when I add childviewcontroller in viewcontroller as subview and disable that view though it is accessible. You can see in this [VIDEO](https://www.dropbox.com/s/et39jodmi57t61p/mac.mov?dl=0).

and my [STORYBOARD](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pki9y7uiphk6fk3/Main.storyboard?dl=0). You can see customview and view_main.

I also make custom class of `NSView` for enable and disable it. and below is code for disable that view though its accessbile.

```
@implementation NSView (customview)
-(void) setEnabled:(BOOL) isEnabled{
    
    for (NSView* subView in self.subviews) {
        
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[NSControl class]]) {
            
            [(NSControl*)subView setEnabled:isEnabled];
        }else  if ([subView isKindOfClass:[NSView class]]) {
            
            [subView setEnabled:isEnabled];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code on button click

```
#pragma -mark All action methods
- (IBAction)sidebarChanged:(ITSidebar *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@: %lu", [sender selectedItem], (unsigned long)[sender selectedIndex]);
}
- (IBAction)starClicked:(id)sender {
    
    //[self.label setStringValue:@"Star"];
    for (NSView* v in [self.custom_view subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self.view_main setEnabled:YES];
    [self.tbl_emojis setEnabled:YES];

}
- (IBAction)watchClicked:(id)sender {
    for (NSView* v in [self.custom_view subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }    
    
    ContactUsVC* vc = [[ContactUsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactUsVC" bundle:nil];
    vc.view.frame = self.custom_view.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self.custom_view addSubview:vc.view];
    [self.view_main setEnabled:NO];
    [self.tbl_emojis setEnabled:NO];
    
}
- (IBAction)tagClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@" Tag clicked");
    for (NSView* v in [self.custom_view subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    
    HelpVC* vc = [[HelpVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpVC" bundle:nil];
    vc.view.frame = self.custom_view.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self.custom_view addSubview:vc.view];
    [self.view_main setEnabled:NO];
    [self.tbl_emojis setEnabled:NO];

    //[self.label setStringValue:@"Tag"];
}
- (IBAction)trashClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@" Trash clicked");
    for (NSView* v in [self.custom_view subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    //id animator = [[ContactUsVC alloc] init];
    ChangePasswordVC* vc = [[ChangePasswordVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChangePasswordVC" bundle:nil];
    vc.view.frame = self.custom_view.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self.custom_view addSubview:vc.view];
    [self.view_main setEnabled:NO];
    [self.tbl_emojis setEnabled:NO];

    // [self.label setStringValue:@"Trash"];
    
}
```

I dont know why behind button action is called on my other view. What should I do for preventing that button action.

Please help me I am stuck here

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement these methods on your subView's class (subClass of NSView*) to avoid mouseClicks bleeding through. Note that i don't call super!

NSView is a subclass of NSResponder, by default not handled events are passed up the responder chain. This is the superview in your example. The solution is to handle the event and not call super.

```
// Avoid mouse clicks from bleeding through
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)event {}
- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent*)event {}
- (void) mouseUp:(NSEvent*)event {}
```